# How to authorize access to all files in a folder via roles

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm upgrading some initial razor code into asp .net razor pages with .net core 5.0.  I've been through many examples on [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0), but it seems that I have to set attributes in all of my .cshtml.cs files.  that feels just sloppy and error prone because something will be forgotten somewhere.

In .NET 4.x Razor syntax, I have an _PageStart.cshtml file, I check the user's role, and I redirect them to the login page if they are not in a particular role. I'd like to do the same in asp .net core using a single file or configuration. I don't want to put an attribute on every pagemodel file, that just seems sloppy. I imagine that I would do something like:

```
options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Club", "ClubAdmin");
```

where ClubAdmin is a role in the application and Club is a folder that contains a bunch of razor pages and sub folders. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you can define a policy in your Startup.cs file that checks for a role and then configure razor pages to Authorize that folder for that specific policy:

```
//define the admin policy
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminPolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
});

services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin", "AdminPolicy");
});
```

The `RequireRole` extension method injects a [RolesAuthorizationRequirement](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e3fd7471db53a559e37ba03dd76408053a80535e/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/RolesAuthorizationRequirement.cs) handler that will validate for the given role during authorization